# Can a Background step relate to only certain test scenarios in a Cypress feature file?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Below is a feature in my Cypress test framework:

```
Background:
    Given User is on the Customer Management landing Page


Scenario: #6 Filter by Customer Name
    When User search for "Jane Doe" in the field Search Customer Name
    Then the search by Customer Name returns only the information related to that customer
```

Scenario #6 above searches for a specific user & validates their information is displayed on the UI.

The issue I'm facing is that sometimes the database which I'm getting data from removes all data, so if I run this test & there's no data returned (Jane Doe doesn't exist), then the test will fail.

What I want to do is add a step where I can do the following:

- Check if "Jane Doe" user exists
- If "Jane Doe" exists, do nothing.
- If "Jane Doe" doesn't exist, create the user, so I can search for them in Scenario #6.

The problem I'm facing is that there are multiple scenario's in this feature file.

Does it make sense to add this step to the `Background` like so, even if the "Jane Doe" user is only used in one specific test scenario:

```
Background:
    Given "Jane Doe" user exists
    And User is on the Customer Management landing Page
```

The "Jane Doe" user is only related to one test scenario here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a need for two backgrounds then you have a very good reason to make a new feature file. So from what I've seen in your post

```
Feature: Jane Doe features

A set of features ... using Jane Doe as an exemplar.

Background: 
  Given Jane Doe ...
  And User is on the Customer Management landing Page

Scenario: Filter by Jane Doe
  ...
```

Rule of thumb: Need two backgrounds, you need a new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add the setup steps you need in that single scenario? Background should apply to everything within the feature, but sometimes you need a little more detail to flesh out one particular test.

Example:

```
Background:
  Given User is on the Customer Management landing Page

# ... various other scenarios without additional setup

Scenario: #6 Filter by Customer Name
  Given the following Customers exist:
    | first name | last name | other information |
    | Jane       | Doe       | ...               |
  When User searches for "Jane Doe" in the field Search Customer Name
  Then the search by Customer Name returns only the information related to that customer
```